# Proposition $3.6$ of Riemannian Geometry by Do Carmo

Tags: proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

I am reading the proof of the proposition $3.6$ of Riemannian Geometry by Do Carmo, which can be read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191489/proposition-3-6-of-do-carmos-riemannian-geometry-why-r1-l-gamma), and I would like to understand why the following statement is true:

> If $l(c) = l(\gamma)$, then $\left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right| = 0$, that is, $v(t) = \ \text{const.}$, and $|r'(t)| = r'(t) > 0$.

Specifically, my doubts are

1. Why $l(c) = l(\gamma)$ imply $\left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right| = 0$?

$l(c) = l(\gamma)$ imply $c'(t) = r'(t)$?

2. Why $\left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right| = 0$ imply $v(t) = \ \text{const.}$, and $|r'(t)| = r'(t) > 0$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would like to make a short comment. Do Carmo's book is really great and covers a large part of basics in Riemannian geometry. But I personnally do not really like all this part concerning the exponential map, normal coordinates *etc.* It is always a pain to me to understand the author's notation and ideas. I would highly recommand to look at the corresponding parts in J. Lee's *Riemannian manifolds: an introduction to curvature*, or S. Gallot, D. Hulin and J. Lafontaine's *Riemannian Geometry*, which provide (in my opinion) a bit clearer proofs.

Note that
$
|c'|^2 = |r'|^2 + |\partial_tf|^2 \geqslant |r'|^2,
$
which yields
$$
|c'| \geqslant |r'|.
$$
Integrating this between $\varepsilon>0$ and $1$ together with the triangular inequality yields
$$
l(c) = \int_0^1|c'| \geqslant \int_{\varepsilon}^1|c'| \geqslant \int_{\varepsilon}^{1} |r'| \underset{(1)}{\geqslant} \left| \int_{\varepsilon}^1 r' \right| = |r(1)-r(\varepsilon)| = r(1)-r(\varepsilon) \to_{\varepsilon \to 0} r(1)  =l (\gamma),
$$
and therefore, we have
$l(c) \geqslant l(\gamma)$. Suppose this last inequality is an equality.

1. This implies that $|c'|-|r'|$ is a non-negative function with vanishing integral, and it follows that $|c'|-|r'|=0$ and thus $|c'| = |r'|$.
   Equality $|c'|^2 = |r'|^2 + |\partial_tf|^2$ gives $|\partial_tf|^2 = 0$.
2. First: note that $\partial_tf = \mathrm{d}\exp_p\left(r(t)v(t)\right)\cdot \left(r(t) v'(t)\right)$. Moreover, the exponential map is supposed to be a diffeomorphism (we are considering a **normal geodesic ball**!), hence $\mathrm{d}\exp_p\left(r(t)v(t)\right)$ is a linear isomorphism. It follows from $|\partial_t f|=0$
   that $r(t)v'(t) = 0$, and therefore, $v'(t) = 0$
   (recall that $r>0$). It follows that $v(t) = v_0$. Second: in inequality $(1)$, there is equality in the triangle inequality (when $\varepsilon \to 0$):
   $$
   \left|\int_{0}^1 r' \right| = \int_0^1|r'|,
   $$
   which implies (by an integration-theory result) that $r'$ has constant sign. As $r(\varepsilon) \to 0$ and $r(1) = l(\gamma)>0$, it follows that $r(1) - r(\varepsilon) >0$ for $\varepsilon >0$ small enough.By the MVT, there is $t \in (\varepsilon,1)$ with $r'(t) = \frac{r(1)-r(\varepsilon)}{1-\varepsilon} >0$. The result follows.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what is this integration-theory result that you mentioned?

Comment: It is the equality case in the triangle inequality for integrals, namely: if $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is integrable such that $\left| \int_{\Omega} f \right| = \int_{\Omega} |f|$, then there exists $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f = e^{i\theta}|f|$. In fact here I only use the real case, which is simpler to show

Comment: I think $\left|\int_{0}^1 r' \right| = \int_0^1|r'|$ does not mean $r'$ has constant sign, since it can be $r'(t)=0$ for some $t$.  If so, we can't get $r'(t)>0$.  How should I understand it?

Comment: By constant sign, I meant $r' \geqslant 0$ everywhere, or $r' \leqslant 0$ everywhere, which follows from the mentioned result of integration.

Comment: @Didier Thanks, but I still can't get $r'(t)>0$.  I agree  that there exists $t_0$ such that $r'(t_0)>0$ by MVT. Besides, I also agree $r'\ge 0$. But in my view, the two things do not mean $r'(t)>0$.   In fact, I feel $r'$ can be zero at some $t_0$, since in this case, the images of $c$ and $\gamma$ can be same.   But if so, the proof of do Carmo is wrong.

Comment: That is why I mentioned at first in my answer two other references that are clearer to me. Do Carmo's proof is not "wrong", but it is too short in my opinion

Comment: @Didier   Very thanks your hint,  in Lee's book, I find the problem of do Carmo's proof. The do Carmo does not assume  $c(t)$ is parametrized by arc length,  so, there is  not $|\frac{dc}{dt}|>0$.  Beacuse of this, we have $r'(t)= |r'(t)| = |\frac{dc}{dt}|>0$. Thanks again.